# how to split all the xml tags in Mule 4?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave, mule4

I have an input xml coming in like this

```
<parent>
    <child type="reference">
        <grandChild name="aaa" action="None">
            <Attribute name="xxx">1</Attribute>
            <grandChild name="bbb" action="None">
                <Attribute name="xxx">1</Attribute>
            </grandChild>
            <grandChild name="ccc" action="None">
                <Attribute name="xxx">1</Attribute>
            </grandChild>
        </grandChild>
        <grandChild name="ddd" action="None">
                <Attribute name="xxx">1</Attribute>
        </grandChild>
    </child>
</parent>
```

and I want to split it to multiple xmls with only parent->child->grandChild tags, in total above example should be converted to 4 xmls (because of 4 grandChild). Like this -

```
<parent>
    <child type="reference">
        <grandChild name="aaa" action="None">
                <Attribute name="xxx">1</Attribute>
        </grandChild>
    </child>
</parent>
```

```
<parent>
    <child type="reference">
        <grandChild name="bbb" action="None">
                <Attribute name="xxx">1</Attribute>
        </grandChild>
    </child>
</parent>
```

```
<parent>
    <child type="reference">
        <grandChild name="ccc" action="None">
                <Attribute name="xxx">1</Attribute>
        </grandChild>
    </child>
</parent>
```

```
<parent>
    <child type="reference">
        <grandChild name="ddd" action="None">
                <Attribute name="xxx">1</Attribute>
        </grandChild>
    </child>
</parent>
```

Can someone please guide me on this? I was looking for some collection splitter alternatives which was there on Mule 3 or any other way possible.

Answer (score 1):

This will  create an array of those xml so if you put this expression in the foreach expression it will do what you need.

```
%dw 2.0
import dw::core::Objects

fun collectChilds(node) = do {
    var children = node.&grandChild default {}
    ---
    (children mapObject ((item, key) -> {
        parent: {
            child @("type": "reference") : {
                (key) : item.&Attribute
            }
        }
    }) pluck ((value, key, index) -> {(key) : value})
    ) ++ (Objects::valueSet(children) flatMap ((item, index) -> collectChilds(item)))
}
---
collectChilds(payload.parent.child)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Did u try running the code, it's giving me error `Cannot coerce Array ([{Attribute @(name: "xxx"): "1",grandChild @(name: "bbb", action: "None"): {A...) to Object` at mapObject as mapObject is expecting an object but we have an Array. I tried casting it but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm on Mule 4.1.3